# How to show label outside the collectionView outline

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my `CollectionViewCell` I am putting a cell, after that I am putting a label on cell.

Now I want to show my label outside the collectionView outline.

**Like This**

[image]

I am set label inside the collection cell **Like This**

```
let cell = collectionViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        cell?.lblDate.text = dateArray[indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.item ==  9{
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245.0/255.0, green: 112.0/255.0, blue: 108/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell?.lblDate.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 30.0)
            cell?.clipsToBounds = false
        }
```

[image]

But I get **Like This**

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about cutting it?

Comment: I want to show my current Date as highlighted or greater than, as compare  to other dates, as you can see in above image

Comment: Still can't understand problem. You don't know how to make it red and bigger?

Comment: Yes **@Vold**,   check my updated question

Comment: Question: How do you show the red stuff? It's just a view with a color? Change its frame (and change the cell property to maskToBound to false) when selected/highlighted...

Comment: take your red cell and make transform(CGAffineTransformScale) to make it bigger. Then unselect property clipToBounds of your UICollectionView

Comment: plz check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** Check whether UILabel's superView is set not to clip:

[image]

or

```
superView.clipsToBounds = false
```

**b)** Place a view into to the bottom view of each cell, set background color to gray-green and clip its size by another subView. Red cell will not be clipped - the effect remains the same

Answer (score 0):

take your red cell and make transform(`CGAffineTransformScale`) to make it bigger. Then unselect property `clipToBounds` of your UICollectionView